# How to get all post parameters in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to get all post parameters of a [symfony](http://symfony.com/) Form.

I used :

```
$all_parameter = $this->get('request')->getParameterHolder()->getAll();
```

and I get this error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::getParameterHolder() in /Library/WebServer/Documents/Symfony/src/Uae/PortailBundle/Controller/NoteController.php on line 95
```

Comment: In case some are searching for symfony 3 : $request = Request::createFromGlobals();

$a = $request->request->all()

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
$this->get('request')->request->all()
```

Comment: When `Request $request` is a parameter for the controller action: `$request->request->all()`

Comment: I think `$this->get('request')` is deprecated in 2.8 and was removed in 3.0. Didn't confirm. Anyway, the @jmq comment nailed it.

Answer (score 9):

Symfony [Request Objects](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html) have quite a few public properties that represent different parts of the request.  Probably the easiest way to describe it is to show you the code for `Request::initialize()`

```
/**
 * Sets the parameters for this request.
 *
 * This method also re-initializes all properties.
 *
 * @param array  $query      The GET parameters
 * @param array  $request    The POST parameters
 * @param array  $attributes The request attributes (parameters parsed from the PATH_INFO, ...)
 * @param array  $cookies    The COOKIE parameters
 * @param array  $files      The FILES parameters
 * @param array  $server     The SERVER parameters
 * @param string $content    The raw body data
 *
 * @api
 */
public function initialize(array $query = array(), array $request = array(), array $attributes = array(), array $cookies = array(), array $files = array(), array $server = array(), $content = null)
{
    $this->request = new ParameterBag($request);
    $this->query = new ParameterBag($query);
    $this->attributes = new ParameterBag($attributes);
    $this->cookies = new ParameterBag($cookies);
    $this->files = new FileBag($files);
    $this->server = new ServerBag($server);
    $this->headers = new HeaderBag($this->server->getHeaders());

    $this->content = $content;
    $this->languages = null;
    $this->charsets = null;
    $this->acceptableContentTypes = null;
    $this->pathInfo = null;
    $this->requestUri = null;
    $this->baseUrl = null;
    $this->basePath = null;
    $this->method = null;
    $this->format = null;
}
```

So, as you can see, `Request::$request` is a `ParameterBag` of the POST parameters.

Comment: * `ParameterBag`, which has `all()` method to get an array with all contained parameters.

Comment: * `ParameterBag`, which has `all()` method to get an array with all contained parameters.