# Symfony Request get all url Parameters

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.2

I have a `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` object and from it I want to fetch all the url paramethers that provided. In other words when the user visits the `http://example.org/soempage?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3`

I want to generate an array that has these values `['param1','param2','param3']` .

Also I have seen this one: [How to get all post parameters in Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738647/how-to-get-all-post-parameters-in-symfony2#10739138)

And I tried the following based on above:

```
    /**
     * @var request Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request
     */
    $parametersToValidate=$request->request->all();
    $parametersToValidate=array_keys($parametersToValidate);
```

And

```
    /**
     * @var request Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request
     */
    $parametersToValidate=$request->all();
    $parametersToValidate=array_keys($parametersToValidate);
```

Without the desired result but instead I get this error message:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "all" of class "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request\

## Edit 1

The request I use int into a static method that validates my input. The method is called via the controller and is implemented like that for reusability purposes.

```
public static function httpRequestShouldHaveSpecificParametersWhenGiven(Request $request,array $parametersThatHttpRequestShouldHave)
    {
        $parametersToValidate=$request->parameters->all();

        if(empty($parametersToValidate)){
            return;
        }
        
        $parameters=array_keys($parametersToValidate);
        
        foreach($parameters as $param){
            if(!in_array($parameters,$parametersThatHttpRequestShouldHave)){            
                throw new InvalidNumberOfParametersException(implode(',',$parametersToValidate),implode(',',$parametersThatHttpRequestShouldHave),implode(',',$diff));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: May we see the entire Controller Action?

Comment: It is not into a contoller but into an anothewr method that I pass it as parameter.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Did you try:

```
$parametersToValidate = $request->query->all();
```

Comment: Yes that helped

Comment: Notice that if you want $_POST params, use : `$request->request->all();`

Comment: Strange that Symfony uses the word 'query' to get GET params, and 'request' to get POST params, when PHP uses REQUEST (through global $_REQUEST var) to get both GET and POST params...